# If statement loop doesnt stop without a break

Tags: python

The code is supposed to read first name, last name and user number from a text file then generate a username for the users. When I run it, it won't stop looping and it is only reading the first line from the text file.
P.S: It stops when I use `break` but we are not supposed to use `break`

```
def get_parts(s):
   lname, fname, code = s.rstrip().split(',')
   lname = lname.lstrip().rstrip()
   fname = fname.lstrip().rstrip()
   code = code.lstrip().rstrip()
   return (fname, lname, code)
  
def make_user(fname, lname, code):
   uname = fname[0:2].lower() + lname[0:2].lower() + code[-3:]
   return uname

def main():
   f = open('clients.txt', 'r')
   print('{:<20s} {:<10s}'.format('Client', 'Username'))
   print('=' * 31)
   while True:
       line = f.readline()
       if line == "":
           print('Error')
       else:
           fname, lname, code = get_parts(line)
           uname = make_user(fname, lname, code)  
       print('{:<20}{:<10}'.format(fname + ' ' + lname, uname))
   f.close()

main()
```

Sample Data in the text file

```
Alias, Smith,12345
lionf ,Mgrgr,32424
Jordan,Danny,32421
Kami, George, 33342
```

Comment: You are using a `while True` loop, the condition is always `True` an so it will never end. A suggestion is to add a `break` after `print("Error")`

Comment: ``` while True``` won't stop looping if you don't ```break```.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you reach the end of the file, the loop won't stop. `readline()` will return an empty string when the end of the file is reached (@Nathan Roberts), but you should make sure this is not happening and just break that loop.

Another solution would be to use `readlines()`. This function returns an array with all the lines in the file and you can iterate through them like in the following example:

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    fname, lname, code = get_parts(line)
    uname = make_user(fname, lname, code)
```

This way you're making sure the loop will be executed only for the number of the lines

Comment: I like your answer, but I have to say that calling `file.readline()` doesn't read the same line every time. It will move on to the next line in the file, but eventually when it reaches the end it will just start returning empty strings.

Comment: I think you're right, thanks for the correction. Anyway, do you have any idea why is the Op getting the same line everytime?

Comment: I don't think that they are actually getting the same line every time. I copied their code and reproduced it. It works properly until the last line of the file and then because it never breaks it keeps printing out the last values that the variables were set to.

Comment: Got it, most likely if they really get the same value, it's because it's only one line in the file or multiple identical lines. Thanks for clarifications.

Comment: Yeah, the way that their code is set up is that if it gets an empty line from `f.readline()` it prints out "error" and then prints the statement at the end of the loop block regardless of how the if statement worked. With `f.readline()` even after reaching the last line of the file, you can keep calling the function and it will keep returning blank strings if there are no more lines in the file. So the program will just keep printing out error and then the last set values for their variables in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an `while True`, that alone will loops forever (because the condition is always, well, True) unless inside the loop you include a way to stop said loop, there are 4 way to do so: the `break` statement, the `return` statement if its inside a function, throwing or raising and exception with the `raise` statement and finally getting an exception in some way intentional or nor.

Beside that, you don't need to use a while-loop for this, open files in python are iterable, that mean you can use them in a for-loop and you get the lines from it and the iteraton will naturally stop when the last line is reached

```
>>> with open("clients.txt") as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line)

        
Alias, Smith,12345

lionf ,Mgrgr,32424

Jordan,Danny,32421

Kami, George, 33342
>>>
```

you get the extra line because the new line character `\n` is included in the line

```
>>> with open("clients.txt") as file:
        print(list(file))

    
['Alias, Smith,12345\n', 'lionf ,Mgrgr,32424\n', 'Jordan,Danny,32421\n', 'Kami, George, 33342']
>>>
```

(calling list(file) or file.readlines() are equivalent)

Another thing is that the more proper way to open a file is using the `with` statement as show in examples above, there are 2 reason for that the first is that automatically close the file for us when we leave that block of code (no more need to manually call file.close()) and the second is that it also does that even in case some error occurs inside that block, which wouldn't happens otherwise.

For some miscellaneous thing, string have the .strip method which does .lstrip and .rstrip simultaneously

```
>>> t="  x  "
>>> t.lstrip()
'x  '
>>> t.rstrip()
'  x'
>>> t.strip()
'x'
>>>
```